# Cordova hybrid app (missing files from my project)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Im working on a hybrid app on cordova 6, I added android, Ios and browser, currently working on android only. My project is in `c:/myApp/www` and the same content of it is in `c:/myApp/platforms/android/assets/www` , when I run cordova on browser everything is there and I can see the project from `Chrome DevTools => source`; but when I run it in android, deploy it to my phone (samsung s5), debug with cable, I look into `Chrome Devtools => source`, I see only `index.html` and `assets` folder, while there has to be a `login.html` and `images` folder and other `JS` files. I even moved the `images` folder to `assets` folder but the `assets` folder is there and `images` folder is not in it!!!

Comment: are you using phonegap cloud based build  / android studio  / cli;' to build your application?

Comment: is images a real folder and not a symlink/shortcut ?

Comment: @ArjunTRaj Im using cordova cli like `cordova build android && cordova run android`

Comment: @n00dl3 no man! the folder is real !! 50 MB of size

Answer (score 0):

All your html and images should be in your main www folder or subfolders of it.

Make sure your images folder exists here:
c:/myApp/www/images

If that's not working, you could try removing and re-adding the platform using the CLI:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

You shouldn't edit your c:/myApp/platforms/android/assets/www folder directly, and you should just let the CLI automatically copy files there when you run `cordova run android`.